# Запрос: выбрать самый дорогой товар, купленный одним покупателем

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

уважаемые разработчики!
Прошу  помочь с запросом: Есть таблицы покупатели Customer,Заказы Orders, Товары Items.
Схема данных ниже.
Требуется найти самый дорогой товар, купленный одним покупателем. То есть если покупателей, который купили этот товар несколько, то этот товар не выводится, если даже он самый дорогой.
Мой код не работает,но не могу понять в чем  проблема:

```
 (Select Customer_id,item_id,Customer_name,MAX(item_price) MostExpensiveItemName
from Customer c join Orders o on c.Customer_id = o.Customer_id
join items i on i.item_id = o.item_id) q
inner join (select Customer_id,item_name,item_price from i right join o on i.item_id = o.item_id
            having count(Customer_id) = 1) s on s.item_id =q.item_id
```

[image: Схема данных]

Comment: *То есть если покупателей, который купили этот товар несколько, то этот товар не выводится, если даже он самый дорогой.* А если один покупатель купил две штуки в одном заказе? в разных заказах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разбирать по шагам

1. Товары у которых у которых только один  покупатель.

   ```
   select  
     item_id 
   from orders 
   group by 
     item_id 
   having 
     count(customer_id) = 1
   ```
2. Найдем заказы у которых товары только с одним покупателем.

   ```
   select 
       orders.* 
   from orders 
       inner join (
        select  
           item_id 
        from orders 
        group by 
           item_id 
        having 
           count(customer_id) = 1
      ) as uniqOrders 
      on uniqOrders.item_id = orders.item_id
   ```
3. Добавим собственно товары и покупателей.

   ```
   select 
       customers.*,
       orders.*,
       items.item_prise 
   from customers
       inner join orders
         on orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
       inner join items
         on items.item_id = orders.item_id 
       inner join (
        select  
           item_id 
        from orders 
        group by 
           item_id 
        having 
           count(customer_id) = 1
      ) as uniqOrders 
      on uniqOrders.item_id = orders.item_id
   ```
4. Поскольку мы получили в итоге что у разыскиваемого товара может быть только один покупатель. Нам нужно отсортировать по цене по убыванию и взять только самую первую запись из результирующего набора. Никаких max и прочих вам не нужно.

PS. Если вам необходимо считать максимум по какой-то другой формуле (orders.quatity*items.items_prise) то просто сотртируете по ней.